# How to use boost bind with member function nested in class with reference parameter?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind

I tried to use `boost::bind` inside a class method, which in turn calls another class method with reference parameter:

```
void some_method() {   
     for_each( con.begin(), con.end(), boost::bind( &comb_str::dfs, this, _1 ) );
}

void dfs( string& str ) {
... 
}
```

With this syntax, I got it compiled using VC++ 2010, but it passed `string` as a copy instead of reference. Then I tried to add `boost_ref( _1 )` and I got compiler error said:

```
Error 1 error C2664: 'R boost::_mfi::mf1<R,T,A1>::operator ()<comb_str>(const U &,A1) const' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'boost::arg<I>' to 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> ' c:\program files\boost\boost_1_44\boost\bind\bind.hpp 313 1
```

**Update**
It actually worked without the need of boost::ref. I really apologize for being careless. Thanks for all your time reading.

Any idea?

Comment: I recall that, in some cases, you have to specify the template arguments to `boost::bind` explicitly. Does that help?

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks for your reply. BoostBind have 77 overloads, I'm really confused what arguments should I supply?

Comment: So you've tried modifying str inside `dfs` and the changes did not propagate to `con`'s content?

Comment: @Eugen Constantin Dinca: Thanks! Sorry all. It does apply reference. I don't need to explicitly add boost::ref.

Comment: Was asking because I had no problem using this `for_each( con.begin(), con.end(), boost::bind( &comb_str::dfs, this, _1 ) );` to modify the contents of `con` inside this `void dfs( string& str )`.